# copy directory including 'base' folder

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, copy, xcopy

I need to copy folderA into folderB via the command line:

```
c:\temp
        \folderA
        \folderB
```

should become

```
c:\temp
         \folderA   
         \folderB\folderA
```

That is, *exactly* the same as if you copied folderA using windows explorer and pasted it into folderB.

This does not work:

```
xcopy /e folder1 folder2\
```

as you end up with the contents of folderA in folderB and not folderA itself.

Funnily enough, `move` does exactly what I want except that it moves instead of copy :)

**How do you copy a folder and include the folder itself as the base folder for the copy?** 
I shouldn't have to use mkdir to create the target folder. (but that gets the job done nastily)

Please dont direct me to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/58989/copying-directory-tree-on-windows) as that does **not** do the above.

**Update:**

Thanks to the answers below using robocopy I found a solution using xcopy that doesnt prompt either:

> xcopy /e /i folderA folderB\folderA

Use the `/i` option to avoid being asked whether the target is a directory or a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
xcopy folder1 folder2\folder1 /e /i
```

Answer (score 1):

`robocopy \folderA \folderB\folderA /s` will create folderA at the destination and perform a recursive copy. Check what other options you may want or require. e.g. `/e` if you want to include empty folders.

Answer (score 0):

[Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

If I understand the parameters correctly, you'd want to do `Robocopy C:\temp\folderA C:\temp\folderB /COPYALL /E /DCOPY:T`

(Copy folder A into location B, preserve all attributes and ACLs, include all subfolders even empty ones, preserve directory timestamps.)

Comment: that doesnt work did you even try it? does exactly the same as xcopy command above, folderA is *not* copied.